# Geting redux-store state inside authProvider in react admin

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

When user login i get the authorization permissions and I've created custom saga and reducer to dispatch action and save that data to the store.

Now I would like to get that data from the redux-store in authProvider if type is "AUTH_GET_PERMISSIONS". In other words whenever user goes from one resource to another AUTH_GET_PERMISSIONS is called and there I need to pass my permissions. I have seen in documentation that they are using local storage to achieve this, but I would really like to avoid using it.

I am using react-admin version 2.9.7

If anyone has some idea, hint or suggestion, to atleast point me in right direction, I would be thankful.

Comment: You want the data ,i.e. your permission whenever "AUTH_GET_PERMISSIONS" is called?

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I wan't the data whenver AUTH_GET_PERMISSIONS is called. But I want to that data in authProvider.

Comment: Can you dispatch actions from authProvider? Like can you access your redux functions from authProvider?